# Deleting node from linked list recursively in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm new to C and I'm still having a hard time understanding how pointers and liked lists work, thus I'm having some issues with all of this.

I'm trying to delete a node from a linked list and I'm using the example on [this link](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/linked-list/delete/), but I can't get it to work.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct voos
{
int numeroVoo;
char ciaAerea[20];
char modeloAeronave[20];
char origem[20];
char destino[20];
int qtdeTotalAssentos;
int qtdeAssentosOcupados;
struct voos *proximo;
} *cadastroVoo;

int cont = 0; //Contador temporario para contar numero de assentos ocupados
void addVoo (cadastroVoo *local) //Add item to list
{
cadastroVoo novo;
novo = (cadastroVoo) malloc(sizeof(struct voos));
char temp[20];
if (novo != NULL)
{
    printf("Informe o numero do voo: \n");
    scanf("%d", &novo->numeroVoo);

    printf("Informe a cia aerea: \n");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(temp);
    strcpy(novo->ciaAerea, temp);

    printf("Informe o modelo da aeronave: \n");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(temp);
    strcpy(novo->modeloAeronave, temp);

    printf("Informe a origem do voo: \n");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(temp);
    strcpy(novo->origem, temp);

    printf("Informe o destino do voo: \n");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(temp);
    strcpy(novo->destino, temp);

    cont++;
    novo->qtdeAssentosOcupados = cont;

    novo->qtdeTotalAssentos = 50;

    novo->proximo = *local;
    *local = novo;
}
}

void listarVoos(cadastroVoo local) //prints list
{
printf("Imprimindo lista atualizada: \n\n\n");
while (local != NULL)
{
    printf("Numero voo: %d\n", local->numeroVoo);
    printf("Cia Aerea: %s\n", local->ciaAerea);
    printf("Modelo aeronave: %s\n", local->modeloAeronave);
    printf("Origem: %s\n", local->origem);
    printf("Destino: %s\n", local->destino);
    printf("Quantidade total de assentos: %d\n", local->qtdeTotalAssentos);
    printf("Quantidade de assentos ocupados: %d\n", local->qtdeAssentosOcupados);
    printf("\n");
    local = local->proximo;
}
}

cadastroVoo *cancelarPassagem(cadastroVoo *local, int numVoo) //deletes item from list
{
// See if we are at end of list.
if (local == NULL) return NULL;

// Check to see if current node is one to be deleted.
if (local->numeroVoo == numVoo)
{
    cadastroVoo *tempNextP;

    tempNextP = local->proximo;

    free(local);

    return tempNextP;
}

// Check the rest of the list, fixing the next pointer in case the next node is the one removed.
local->proximo = cancelarPassagem(local->proximo, numVoo);

//Return the pointer to where we were called from.  Since we did not remove this node it will be the same.
return local;
}

int main()
{
cadastroVoo cadastro = NULL;
char op;
while(op != 'f')
{
    printf("Escolha a opcao:\n");
    printf("a - Incluir voos:\n");
    printf("b - Listar voos:\n");
    printf("c - Reservar assento em um voo:\n");
    printf("d - Cancelar voo:\n");
    printf("e - Cancelar passagem:\n");
    printf("f - Sair:\n");
    op = getche();
    printf("\n");
    switch(op)
    {
    case 'a':
        {
            printf("Incluir voo. \n");
            addVoo(&cadastro);
            printf("Voo incluso.\n");
            break;
        }
    case 'b':
        {
            listarVoos(cadastro);
            break;
        }
    case 'c':
        {
            printf("Reservar assento em um voo. \n");
            addVoo(&cadastro);
            printf("Assento reservado.\n");
            break;
        }
    case 'd':
        {
            /**
            *while (cancelarVoo != NULL) cancelarVoo()
            */
            break;
        }
    case 'e':
        {
            int numVoo;
            printf("Informe o numero do voo que deseja cancelar a passagem: \n");
            scanf("%d", &numVoo);
            cancelarPassagem(&cadastro, numVoo);
            printf("Passagem cancelada");
            break;
        }
    case 'f': break;
    default:
        {
            printf("Opcao invalida.");
            break;
        }
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

In the method declaration, if I pass:

```
cadastroVoo *cancelarPassagem(cadastroVoo *local, int numVoo)
```

I get the error: request for member 'numeroVoo' in something not a structure or union

But if I pass

```
cadastroVoo *cancelarPassagem(cadastroVoo local, int numVoo)
```

It runs, but then when I choose the option that calls this method, I'll get the message on windows that it stopped working.

Does anyone have any idea what could be going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not include links. Show here how the list is defined.

Comment: `cadastroVoo` must already be a pointer. Well, check your warnings. Because your modification should also include return type and it didn't change. Also you have to show us how you allocate your list and its definition.

Comment: My compilation generates 4 warnings and 4 errors.

Comment: Yeah, the 4 errors I get are all error: request for member ***** in something not a structure or union

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are not passing a pointer to the function. I tried your code here and the logic is working fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct cadastroVoo {
    struct cadastroVoo *proximo;
    int numero;
} CadastroVoo;

CadastroVoo *cancelarPassagem(CadastroVoo *local, int num);

void inserir(CadastroVoo *cabeca, int num) {
    CadastroVoo *p = (CadastroVoo *) malloc(sizeof(CadastroVoo)); 
    p->proximo = cabeca->proximo;
    p->numero = num;
    cabeca->proximo = p;
}

CadastroVoo *cancelarPassagem(CadastroVoo *local, int num) {
    if (local == NULL) return NULL;
    printf("> %d\n", local->numero);
    printf("> %p\n", local->proximo);
    if (local->numero == num) {
        CadastroVoo *proximo = local->proximo;
        free(local);
        return proximo;
    } 
    local->proximo = cancelarPassagem(local->proximo, num);
    return local;
}   

int main() {
    CadastroVoo *cabeca = (CadastroVoo *) malloc(sizeof(CadastroVoo)); 
    cabeca->proximo = NULL;

    inserir(cabeca, 10);
    inserir(cabeca, 20);
    inserir(cabeca, 30);
    inserir(cabeca, 40);
    inserir(cabeca, 50);

    cancelarPassagem(cabeca->proximo, 20);

    CadastroVoo *p = cabeca->proximo;
    while (p != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", p->numero);
        p = p->proximo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to give references instead of the actual code in your question.

Nevertheless here is a simplified demonstrative program that uses recursive methods with a singly linked list. I am sure it does what you need. Investigate it and change your project accordingly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct List
{
    int data;
    struct List *next;
} List;

List * add_node( List *head, int data )
{
    if ( head == NULL )
    {
        head = malloc( sizeof( List ) );
        head->data = data;
        head->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        head->next = add_node( head->next, data );
    }

    return head;
}

List * remove_node( List *head, int data )
{
    if ( head != NULL )
    {
        if ( head->data == data )
        {
            List *tmp = head;
            head = head->next;
            free( tmp );
        }
        else
        {
            head->next = remove_node( head->next, data );
        }
    }

    return head;
}

void display_list( List *head )
{
    if ( head != NULL )
    {
        printf( "%d ", head->data );
        display_list( head->next );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    const int N = 10;
    List *head = NULL;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    {
        head = add_node( head, i );
        display_list( head );
        printf( "\n" );
    }

    for ( int i = N; i != 0; i-- ) 
    {
        head = remove_node( head, i - 1 );
        display_list( head );
        printf( "\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 
0 1 
0 1 2 
0 1 2 3 
0 1 2 3 4 
0 1 2 3 4 5 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
0 1 2 3 4 5 
0 1 2 3 4 
0 1 2 3 
0 1 2 
0 1 
0
```